# Installation of Pyside1.2.4 on Redhat Linux version6.8

Tags: pyside, redhat

I am trying to install Pyside1.2.4 on RHEL 6.8. When I run the setup.py install I get the following error message

> Failed to find cmake. Please specify cmake with cmake --parameter.

Any help would be welcome

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that you need cmake, so :

```
yum install cmake
```

would probably be a good idea.
You might need to install other packages.

Comment: The yum install cmake does not work. I downloaded the cmake package and when i tried to install cmake using the ./bootstrap command i get the following errors. Error when making cmake:cannot find appropriate C++ compiler in the system. please specify one using environment variable CXX.

Comment: So you need a whole development environment, with g++ and probably many libraries
The needed deb packages are :
sudo apt-get install build-essential git cmake libqt4-dev libphonon-dev python2.7-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev qtmobility-dev libqtwebkit-dev
. I don't know the equivalents for RHEL.